# Get access to web service from remote machine

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

I created a windows service,by this windows service i am publishing the web service

through a server for access to remote machines.

when i am create the setup of that particular and install it will access only from local

machine but cant access those web service from remote machine.

but at the time when i am debugging the code the service will start properly and will access

from remote machine also.

what i can do for this.

plz help me out...

thanks in advance
(sorry for grammar and spelling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a firewall exception